# AVAudioPlayer doesn't load sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, avfoundation

For whatever reason, I'm having trouble loading up a sound with the `AVAudioPlayer`. I am testing it on my iPad device.

My code is fairly straight forward, nothing fancy. The framework is imported, delegate implemented. In my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                           initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
                                           error:NULL];
[theAudio setDelegate:self];
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio play];
```

This fails to play the audio. However, by coincidence, when I show a `UIAlertView` immediately after, I can hear the first 2 seconds of the audio clip play. That is, my app loads, I hear two seconds of audio, then the alert pops up and cuts off the audio.

So it would appear the `AVAudioPlayer` code somewhat seems to work.

Any idea on whats going on and how I can simply get the audio to play?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are using ARC, and therefore that the AVAudioPlayer is deallocated when the variable goes out of scope. You have to declare the `theAudio` variable as an instance variable, and assign it in the viewDidLoad. So, in your .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
    ...
}
...
@end
```

Then, get rid of the `AVAudioPlayer *` from the line where you assign `theAudio` in viewDidLoad. This will cause your view controller to retain the audio player, and thus will prevent the player from being deallocated before playback.